# Adding shapes in List row of SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to create a List View where rows looks like this:

[image]

However, I am unable to align the `Circle` on the leading side. Tried using `Spacer()`, `HStack` within `VStack`, it just doesn't work. Here's my code and its output.

```
struct PeopleView: View {
    
    let people = ["Adam", "James"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(person)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("People", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: tui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you don't need shape itself in this case, but only as a mask to visually present text in circle.

So the solution can be like following

[image: demo]

```
HStack {
    Text(person.prefix(2).uppercased()).bold()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .mask(Circle())          // << shaping text !!

    Spacer()
    VStack {
        Text("\(person)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some views in SwiftUI fill all available space. Such views are shapes, colors, spacers, dividers, and `GeometryReader`.

Your `Circle` is a shape and it behaves similarly like a `Spacer` (in terms of filling space).

If you replace `Circle` with an *image* of a circle it will work:

```
ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .imageScale(.large)
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Text("\(person)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because you did not give a fixed (or relative) frame to the `Circle` Shape, so the `Circle` is taking up the maximum available width.

If you add a `frame(width:height:)`, everything should work correctly:

[image: The expected result]

```
struct PeopleView: View {
    
    let people = ["Adam", "James"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(person)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("People", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```