# Custom list accessory

Tags: swiftui, alignment, swiftui-list, accessoryview

I want to make a custom list accessory view in SwiftUI.

My idea:

```swift
List {
    Button(action: {}, label: {
        HStack {
            Text("CutomView")
            Spacer()
            Circle().frame(alignment: .trailing)
        }
    })
            
    Button(action: {}, label: {
        HStack {
            Text("SF Symbol")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "circle").imageScale(.large)
        }
    })
}
```

Resulting in:
[image: SwiftUI screenshot]

It kinda does work with

```swift
Circle().frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .trailing)
```

but that feels really bad to me... Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help/resources also about aligning the text properly is appreciated ^.^

What I know is that the `Spacer` in the first row seems not to 'work' and causing the `Circle` to use up all the space in the row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding shapes in List row of SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717688/adding-shapes-in-list-row-of-swiftui)

Comment: If you want to use Circle as View, then frame will be the best option. If you do not specify a frame, the Circle will take the whole width.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thank you very much! Using `.mask(...)` here is probably what I want. However, I still fail to see the best way to apply a mask to my "empty" circle...

Comment: @thisIsTheFoxe Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62718111/8697793) as well. `Circle` will try to fill all available space. Which means you can't use Circle *normally*. You need to use some other view and clip/mask/overlay it with a Circle. Alternatively you can just use frame (if you specify the width explicitly).