# SwiftUI: List, NavigationLink, and badges

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, hstack

I'm working on my first SwiftUI app, and in it would like to display a `List` of categories, with a badge indicating the number of items in that category.  The title of the category would be on the left, and the badge would be right-aligned on the row.  The list would consist of `NavigationLink`s so that tapping on one would drill further down into the view hierarchy.  The code I've written to render the `NavigationLink`s looks like this:

```
        List {
            ForEach(myItems.indices) { categoryIndex in
                let category = categories[categoryIndex]
                let title = category.title
                let fetchReq = FetchRequest<MyEntity>(entity: MyEntity(),
                                            animation: .default)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: MyItemView()) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(title)
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            
                            Text("\(myItemsDict[category]?.count ?? 0)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 12))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

While it does render a functional `NavigationLink`, the badge is not displayed right-aligned, as I had hoped.  Instead, it looks like this:

[image]

I know I'm getting hung up on something in my `HStack`, but am not sure what.  How do I get it so that the category title Text takes up the majority of the row, with the badge right-aligned in the row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding shapes in List row of SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717688/adding-shapes-in-list-row-of-swiftui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't know how big your `Circle` should be, so the `Spacer` doesn't do anything. You should set a fixed frame for it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<2) { categoryIndex in
                let title = "Logins"
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hi")) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(title)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25) // here!
                            
                            Text("5")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 12))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]